# Referencing components inside of composite components (and vice versa)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I'm having one or two problems with Primefaces (v5.2):

**Referencing components *inside* composite components**

Let's say I have a composite component that wraps an inputfield:

**myinputfield.xhtml**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

(Of course the real application does "a little" more.)

In my page I now use this field like this:

**index.xhtml**

```
<my:myinputputfield value=#{controller.inputstring} />
```

This works. *But*:
Know I want to reference that inner inputfield from outside, for example for labels or messages. Something *like*:

```html
<p:inputLabel for="mif" value="Your Input:"/>
<my:myinputputfield id="mif" value=#{controller.inputstring} />
<p:message for="mif" />
```

Of course that doesn't work, because `id` isn't defined for `myinputfield`.
So the first idea that pops to mind is to extent the cc like this:

**myinputfield.xhtml *(new)***

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Which does not work as well. I tried different things and read different answers and articles without finding an answer to this.

---

The second problem is the complete opposite:

**Referencing components *outside* composite components**

This time imagine it the other way around. I have a customized label, message or in my case a tooltip:

**mytooltip.xhtml**

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="for" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:toolTip for="#{cc.attrs.for}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

This time I want to attach `mytooltip` to an existing component:

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:outputtext id="ot" value="Hello World!" />
<my:mytooltip for="ot" value="since 1974" />
```

Which also does not work. (Of course!?)

This problem I had some time ago and solved it by inclduing the outputText in the composite component.

---

But I have the feeling it should be possible to manage both user cases. But how?

Comment: Always best btw to ask 1 question per question. Issue in this case is that a composite component is **always** naming container. Read about those in this context (and check the html source to see it in action, check the real client id of the inputtext)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. **Referencing components *inside* composite components**

   give the internal input a static id

   ```
   <composite:interface>
       <composite:attribute name="value" />
       ...
   </composite:interface>

   <composite:implementation>
       <h:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
   </composite:implementation>
   ```

   reference the internal component as with any naming container:

   ```
   <p:inputLabel for="mif:input" value="Your Input:"/>
   <my:myinputputfield id="mif" value=#{controller.inputstring} />
   <p:message for="mif:input" />
   ```

2. **Referencing components *outside* composite components**

   the *canonical* way is to use the full client id:

   ```
   <h:form id="form">
       <h:outputText id="ot" value="Hello World!" />
       <my:mytooltip for=":form:ot" value="since 1974" />
   </h:form>
   ```

   but, since you are passing the search expression to a PF component, you can also:

   ```
   <h:form>
       <h:outputText id="ot" value="Hello World!" />
       <my:mytooltip for="@form:ot" value="since 1974" />
   </h:form>
   ```

   or generically:

   ```
   <p:tabView>
       <p:tab title="random tab">
           <h:outputText id="ot" value="Hello World!" />
           <my:mytooltip for="@namingcontainer:ot" value="since 1974" />
       </p:tab>
   </p:tabView>
   ```

   or even:

   ```
   <h:outputText value="Hello World!" />
   <my:mytooltip for="@composite:@previous" value="since 1974" />
   ```

   however, in such cases, a [tag-component/facelet-tag-file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6822269/2911357) could be a better approach.

Comment: add 1: the referencing works, and it turned out, that I oversimplified the problem. (It's about a parametrerized "required" tag that works, but does not generate the asterisk on the label. I'll put on another question for that one if I can't figured it out by myself.) - add 2: I'll look into that, when I have the time. It's probably a worthwhile read anyway.